# Google Drive video url is not working for larger files in react player in react js

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, react-player

Code:-

```
<ReactPlayer url="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1JOZBkMwOllSNg7ameXnAj1dlagusMeux" controls={true} />
```

I have already changes the permission to public and editor.
But this url not working for larger size.
Can somebody help, how to make it working.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the link doesn't point to a video file as it's a download link you cannot use react-player.

google drive allows you to embed items

use

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JOZBkMwOllSNg7ameXnAj1dlagusMeux/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ohh, I haven't thought that way. Thank you sir for your response. It worked!!!!