# I 'am planing to making a videoplattform in React using Google Drive is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api

I'm going to build a video platform with instructional videos.
Can I utilize movies from Google Drive for my React app, where users log in to view my films?
I would like to implement an API integration so that when I add movies to Drive, they automatically appear in the app.
Will this integration provide a smooth experience for users, or are there any potential issues they may encounter?

I'm just in the planning phase right now, so I'm a little curious about any problems along the way.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is far too broad of a question for this site, we can help you with programming problems, but the overarching design of your system is up to you.

Comment: the best way to learn is to: write down your requirements, and then **try**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. I would recommend reviewing the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk) for calls that will return links to your videos and use iframes to embed the videos as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775989/google-drive-video-url-is-not-working-for-larger-files-in-react-player-in-react)!